# How to populate asp:GridView from code?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, binding, populate

I have a `List<string[]> items` list filled with arrays of strings in my code. On the ASPX page, I have added a new grid view control:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductList" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" EnableViewState="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="ProductName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierName" HeaderText="Supplier" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SupplierName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Price" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I know that I should specify the DataSourceID attribute for the grid view in a fashion similar to this:

```
<asp:GridView ... `DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" ... > 
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetProducts" TypeName="ProductsBLL">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

But, I don't know what do `OldValuesParameterFormatString`, `SelectMethod` and `TypeName` attributes represent. Also, I don't have the database to bind to, I just have the list of string arrays named `items`. Can you help me populate the grid view? It is not necessary to do it through the binding at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't even need an ObjectDataSource. At Page_Load in the codebehind, you can parse through the string array list and create a DataTable on the fly.

Make sure to wrap this around a `Not Page.IsPostback` so that it doesn't rebind on postback.

```
List<string[]> stringList = null;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;
dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("SupplierName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
dt.Columns.Add("Discontinued", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

foreach (string[] s in stringList) {
    foreach (string str in s) {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ProductName"] = s[0];
        dr["CategoryName"] = s[1];
        dr["SupplierName"] = s[2];
        dr["UnitPrice"] = s[3];
        dr["Discontinued"] = s[4];
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
ProductList.DataSource = dt;
ProductList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your answer included everything I needed to implement this in my own project..... A thousand thanks'

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You'll have to change some of this code to match your needs.  I'm making assumptions on the data types stored in your `string[]` based on the `GridView` code you provided.

You'll want to look into creating a `class` to use for your items, instead of a `string[]`. Maybe something like:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
}
```

You'd then need something to translate the `string[]` into `MyObject`:

```
private MyObject ConvertToMyObject(string[] values)
{
    var myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.ProductName = values[0];
    myObject.CategoryName = values[1];
    myObject.SupplierName = values[2];

    decimal unitPrice;
    if (decimal.TryParse(values[3], out unitPrice))
    {
        myObject.UnitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    bool discontinued;
    if (boo.TryParse(values[4], out discontinued))
    {
        myObject.Discontinued = values[4];
    }
}
```

Then you could use that method in your code and then bind:

```
protected void Page_Load(parameters here)
{
    if (IsPostback)
    {
        var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
        foreach (string[] values in items)
        {
            myObjects.Add(ConvertToMyObject(values));
        }

        ProductList.DataSource = myObjects;
        ProductList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Like I said in the comment, make sure you have access to `items` in the `Page_Load` event handler.  Also, I typed this from memory, forgot the parameters in `Page_Load`.  You most likely already have a `Page_Load` handler in your code behind though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
List<string[]> items = List<string[]>();
//add items to List

GridView1.DataSource = items;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Your GridView

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="stringLabel" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```