# Manually filled GridView is it possible to have differing Captions for headers?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm using a gridview.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="HJournalGridView" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="+" />
            <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="C1" />
            <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="C2" />
            <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="C3" />
            <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="C4" />
        </Columns>
```

And I'm filling it manually as described in this post: [How to populate asp:GridView from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958457/how-to-populate-aspgridview-from-code)

I stumbled upon the problem there that the displayed name had to be identical to the name used in the row.

```
 DataRow hJournalRow = hJournalData.NewRow();
 hJournalRow["Transaction"] = "Test";
 hJournalRow["DateTimeDevice"] = "19.06.2019 09:20:47";
 hJournalData.Rows.Add(hJournalRow);

 this.HJournalGridView.DataSource = hJournalData;
 this.HJournalGridView.DataBind();
```

The above code produced an error until I have a column whichs headername is identical to the ["Transaction"]... used.

Now my question is: Is it possible to still use Transaction when assigning the data but at the same time display "Meine Transaktion" as caption on hte html page?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

While assigning a row value, we need to either mention column index or the column name of the datatable. We can acheive your requirement by the following steps.

In asp:BoundField assign "Transaction" for DataField and "Meine Transaktion" for HeaderText

```
<asp:GridView ID="HJournalGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="+" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Transaction" HeaderText="Meine Transaktion" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimeDevice" HeaderText="Date-Time Device" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="C3" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="C4" />
                </Columns>  
            </asp:GridView>
```

In Code behind

```
DataRow hJournalRow = hJournalData.NewRow();
hJournalRow["Transaction"] = $"Test {i}";
hJournalRow["DateTimeDevice"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
hJournalData.Rows.Add(hJournalRow);
```